# Putting image into specific cell of draw grids

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I'm making a game of connect 4 in delpi. I need to put the correct coloured circle in the correct place, according to where the user has clicked. How do you load an image (JPEG prefereably) into a specific cell?

I have no idea where to start with this (because my teachers are useless lol) so any help would be so appreciated.!!

on form create:

```
 images:=timagelist.Create(self);
 image1:=tjpegimage.Create;
 image2:=tjpegimage.Create;
 bimage1:=tbitmap.Create;
 bimage2:=tbitmap.Create;
try
image1.loadfromfile('red.jpg') ;
bimage1.Assign(image1);
image2.loadfromfile('yellow.jpg') ;
bimage2.Assign(image2);
finally
  image1.free;
  image2.free;
end;
images.Add(bimage1,nil);
images.Add(bimage2,nil) ;
```

on drawcell:

```
  row:=c4grid.Row;
col:=c4grid.Col;
images.Draw(c4grid.Canvas,row,col,0);
```

So far nothing happens, and there is no evidence that you can actually click the cell. Any help/advice/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: OT: I bet JPEG is not the best format of the images you want to use rather than PNG.

Comment: Please provide complete procedures/functions. Instead of a `TImageList` I suggest you use an array to keep the images. The `OnDraw()` event is called for each cell (that needs to be painted) in turn. The `Rect` parameter tells you where to draw and the `ACol` and `ARow` parameters specify the cell.

Comment: The demo in folder examples/gridexamples/embedded_images of your Lazarus installation (at least in v2.0+) shows how images can be added to a stringgrid.